# Clear Screen in SQL*Plus

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I'm running the following report but getting an error

```
/* Simple table formatting */

clear screen;
accept Report_File char prompt 'Enter a file name for summary report ';

/*Set up column headers*/
col StoreCode format A8 heading 'Store Code';
col DESCRIPTION format A8 heading 'Item Description';
col PRICE format $999999.99 heading 'Price';
col QUANTITY format 999 heading 'Quantity';
col (Price*Quantity) format $999999.99 heading 'Value';

/*Format and title pages */

set Pause off;
set Feedback off;
set Space 6;
set newpage 2;
set pagesize 54;
set linesize 200;
set underline =;
title center 'Current Stock Value by Store' skip 2 left -
            'prepared by Jason Kemeys' &Report_Officer right -
            &Todays_Date skip4;
btitle center format 999 SQL.PNO;

/* Set breaks and computes */

break on StoreCode skip 2 on SuppCode skip 1 on Report;
compute sum of (Price*Quantity) on StoreCode;
compute sum of (Price*Quantity) on Report;

/*Select data & send to file*/

spool &Report_File;

select StoreCode, Description, Quantity, Price, (Price*Quantity)
from Stocks
order by StoreCode;

spool off;

/* Clear all settings */

clear breaks;
clear columns;
clear computes;
set Pause on;
```

Just need to know why its showing the error and how to get it running; first time doing a report in SQL.

This is the error I'm getting

> clear screen;
>   * ERROR at line 2: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Answer (score 33):

`cl scr` is the command used to clear screen in SQL.

Answer (score 10):

I suspect this is dependent on the version of Oracle you are using.

This [should work in version 11.2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve012.htm#SQPUG033) but to quote from the [10g documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12012.htm#SQPUG033):

> CLEAR SCREEN is not available in SQL*Plus.

The same note isn't there in the [11.1 documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b31189/ch12012.htm#SQPUG033), which would imply that you're using Oracle 10g or earlier. If this supposition is true then there's little that you can do.

It's *possible* that you can utilise the [`host`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch4.htm#sthref891) command in SQL*Plus to run [`cls`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cls_%28command%29), if you're using Windows, or [`clear`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/clear), if you're using Linux, but I'm not certain that it would have exactly the same effect. If it were possible it would simply be:

```
host cls
```

`host` runs an operating system command from SQL*Plus, and so will *appear* to clear the screen.

Comment: on oracle linux 7 machine typing at sql plus terminal "host clear" would clean the screen.

Comment: It would clear the screen, yes @xiarnousx. What I say I'm unsure about is whether it has an identical effect to `clear` in SQL*Plus. I doubt it... Though it may _appear_ as though it does.

Answer (score 6):

simply use `cl scr` command to clear the SQL plus.

Answer (score 0):

Very few occurances of ";" in your code is actually needed. For example, the "clear screen" command to start with, doesn't need a semicolon. It will work, when you add one, but I wouldn't be sure about all the subsequent commands in that same file. Commands that need them, are limited to INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, COMMIT, ROLLBACK, and such.

Secondly, if you get weird feedback from SQL-files, and if you have written them outside of Linux/Unix, this often ends up in SQLPLUS complaining about invisible characters. Look at that file via both VI and CAT commands, and note anything weird.